# Elementwise inequality to norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $x=[x_1,\dots,x_n],y=[y_1,\dots,y_n]\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose the elements of $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative and satisfy $$0\le x_i\le y_i$$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

**The question is**: do we have $\|x\|\le\|y\|$ for all norms (not just $\ell_p$ norms)?

It is trivial to prove for $\ell_p$ norms. However, how to prove it for all norms based on the fundamental properties of norms: (i) $\|x\|\ge0$ (ii) $\|ax\|=|a|\|x\|$, (iii) $\|x+y\|\le\|x\|+\|y\|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take the norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $$\|(a,b)\|=\max \{|a|, |b-a|\}.$$   (One has to check that this is a norm). Then the vector $(1,2)$ has norm $1$, because $$\|(1,2)\|=\max\{1, 2-1\}=1.$$  However, the vector $(0,2)$, which is pointwise between $(0,0)$ and $(1,2)$, has norm $2$.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes if the basis is 1-suppression unconditional, which means that for any scalars $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ and any subset $S$ of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, $$\|\sum_{i\in S}a_ie_i\|\leqslant \|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i\|,$$ but general norms need not have this property.

Here, $e_1=(1, 0, \ldots,0)$, $e_2=(0,1, \ldots, 0)$, and so on.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I am not sure if it is a norm.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{F}$ be finite set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for each $0\neq \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists $\vec{y}\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}\neq 0$. Then $$\|\vec{x}\|=\max_{\vec{z}\in \mathcal{F}} |\vec{x}\cdot \vec{z}|$$ is a norm. You should check this for yourself. 

The norm I gave above is a specific example of such a construction with $\mathcal{F}=\{(1,0), (-1,1)\}$.